# Windows 10 BSOD due to HID

Tags: windows-10, drivers, hid

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode
Date:          28/11/2018 16:34:44
Event ID:      10111
Task Category: User-mode Driver problems.
Level:         Critical
Keywords:      
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      DESKTOP-3JS743D
Description:
The device HID-compliant headset (location (unknown)) is offline due to a user-mode driver crash.  Windows will attempt to restart the device 5 more times.  Please contact the device manufacturer for more information about this problem.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode" Guid="{2e35aaeb-857f-4beb-a418-2e6c0e54d988}" />
    <EventID>10111</EventID>
    <Version>1</Version>
    <Level>1</Level>
    <Task>64</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x2000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-11-28T16:34:44.466142000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>1122</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="740" ThreadID="860" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-3JS743D</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <UserData>
    <UmdfDeviceOffline xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/DriverFrameworks/UserMode/Event">
      <LifetimeId>{714af0f3-18c1-4dd0-8385-17569f8faac6}</LifetimeId>
      <FriendlyName>HID-compliant headset</FriendlyName>
      <Location>(unknown)</Location>
      <InstanceId>HID\VID_0951&amp;PID_16A4&amp;MI_03&amp;COL02\7&amp;1C94FA2&amp;0&amp;0001</InstanceId>
      <RestartCount>5</RestartCount>
    </UmdfDeviceOffline>
  </UserData>
</Event>
```

Can anyone help me with this crash? I dont really understand how I can fix this. The driver files it refers to are `c:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\UMDF\HidTelephony.dll` and `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\WudfRD.sys`

All drivers are up to date. Headset is the HyperX Cloud.

Comment: WinDB should be used to analyze the .dmp file.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/cLh6ajd1

Comment: [BlueScreenView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) is more of use.

Comment: @harrymc - BlueScreenView is a waste of time.  It can incorrectly identify the reason a BSOD happens, WinDBG takes a little more time and skill, but its output is always correct.

Comment: Either way the results are in the pastebin. When the headset is unplugged no problems...

Comment: @Ramhound: Your statement is incorrect. With BlueScreenView I have solved several problems on this site. But since you have convinced the poster not to cooperate, I'll let you continue here.

Comment: The crash is calling out bfv.exe so which application are you running?

Comment: @harrymc - I have personally seen Blue Screen Viewer incorrectly call out a cause for a BSOD.  So my statement isn’t incorrect.

Comment: battlefieldV but it's not the only application that it's crashed with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was entirely unrelated to Drivers and ended up being bad CPU voltage settings.

Comment: Care to add the diagnostics that lead you to this?

Comment: I am also interested in the diagnostics. I recently upgraded motherboard, CPU and RAM and also have a HyperX Cloud 2 that seems to cause BSoDs, and event log with the exact same message and InstanceId.

Do you by any chance have an Asus ROG Strix Z390-F with an I7-9700k?